# issue with find -exec cp

Tags: shell, find, cp

Consider this example:

```
touch test0
touch timestamp
touch test1
sudo find /var/www/import -iname 'test*' -newer timestamp -exec cp {} new \;
```

It actually copies file test1, but it returns the message:

```
cp: `/var/www/import/new/test1' and `new/test1' are the same file
```

What am I doing wrong?

2nd question, can I use "+" with this command so that files are copied in a single "bundle"? There are thousands of files!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

That's OK. `find` finds already copied files in `new` and tries to copy them again, therefore a warning message is displayed.

> can I use "+" with this command so that files are copied in a single "bundle"? There are thousands of files!

Yes, but you need to modify you command this way:

```
find /var/www/import -iname 'test*' -newer timestamp -exec cp -t new {} +
```

because `{}` must be at the end of exec statement in this case.

Comment: +1 for `cp -t`.  In the example, that warning may be harmless, but Mike said he was really copying thousands of files, so maybe ignoring the errors is a bad idea, because there might be other types of errors that are hard to see.

Answer (score 4):

Add an `echo` before the `cp` and you'll see it's doing

```
cp new/test1 new
cp test1 new
```

That's because `find` doesn't just look in the current directory, it looks in all subdirectories.

Alternatives:

Tell `find` to not look in subdirectories:

```
find /var/www/import -maxdepth 1 \
    -iname 'test*' -newer timestamp -exec cp {} new \;
```

Tell `find` to ignore the `new` subdirectory:

```
find /var/www/import -type d -name new -prune -o \
    -iname 'test*' -newer timestamp -exec cp {} new \;
```

Copy the files into a directory outside of `/var/www/import`:

```
find /var/www/import \
    -iname 'test*' -newer timestamp -exec cp {} /var/www/import.new \;
```

But if you have subdirectories, you'll end up losing any files that have the same names.

e.g. if you have

```
test0
test1
scripts/test1
```

then you'll end up with

```
test0
test1
new/test1
scripts/test1
```

which `test1` got copied to `new`?

There's a few ways to handle this, but the easiest and most efficient way I can think of is to use `cp --parents`

```
cd /var/www/import
find . -type d -name new -prune -o \
    -type f -iname 'test*' -newer timestamp -exec cp --parents {} new \;
```

that will give you

```
test0
test1
new/test1
new/scripts/test1
scripts/test1
```

Rush already answered the second part of your question, so I won't repeat him.